# Vue, how to get an empty line if I select an option?

Tags: vue.js, if-statement

There is a dropdown menu with 3 selections. Whatever you select, it will be shown as text on the right.
How do I manage that the "Choice1" is not shown at all? It should be just an empty line if you click on "Choice1" while "Choice2" and "Choice3" are still shown. Right now all three options are shown.

````
      { id: 2, value: "Choice1" },
      { id: 3, value: "Choice2" },
      { id: 4, value: "Choice3" },
    ],

v-model="Example.addressUserModel"
                    :items="addressitems"
                    return-object
                    item-text="value"
                    item-value="id"
                    dense
                    outlined
                    rounded

 v-if="Example.addressUserModel" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 1%">
                        {{Example.addressUserModel.value}} ```
````

Comment: You can replace {{Example.addressUserModel.value}} by {{Example.addressUserModel.value !== 'Choice1' ? Example.addressUserModel.value : ''}}

Comment: Iam using ternary operator to check if the selected value is Choice1 . If yes then print '' else print the selected option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the interpolation content by

```
{{Example.addressUserModel.value !== 'Choice1' ? Example.addressUserModel.value : ''}}
```

Above I have used the ternary operator to check if the selected value is Choice1 . If yes then print '' else print the selected option

Comment: @skyhigh23 - Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer